# How to tell "git show" not to show any diffs?

Tags: git, git-show

How do I do a `git show` and show the default `git show` output, but **without** showing any diffs?

e.g.,

```
$ git show
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
commit 2668e3608e (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Tue May 31 19:10:00 2022 -0700

    Fast-tracking GitHub CI Windows build fixes.
```

*(note: I don't want a diff shown here after the commit comment)*

Answer (score 0):

```
git show --no-patch
git log --no-patch  
git show -s
git log -s
```

"patch" is a term for a type of "diff".

Documentation:

> ```
>    -s, --no-patch
>    Suppress diff output. Useful for commands like git show that show the patch by default, 
>    or to cancel the effect of --patch.
> ```

[`git show --help`]